# CakePHP 4 HTML Helper Link Outside of Prefix

Tags: php, cakephp

I set up a prefix for cooking related sections of my application and moved the controllers/views into the appropriate 'Cooking' directories (e.g., cooking/recipes, cooking/ingredients, etc).

When I use the HTML helper for links outside of this prefix in one of the views, it still adds the prefix to the URL.

I created a routing prefix with the following:

```
$routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);
$routes->prefix('cooking', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
    $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Recipes', 'action' => 'index']);
    $builder->fallbacks();
});
```

When I use a HTML helper to create links in an associated view, it adds the prefix. E.g., using:

```
$this->Html->link(
    $recipe->user->name, ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $recipe->user->id]
);
```

Results in a link for `http://mysite.local/cooking/users/1` instead of `http://mysite.local/users/1` without the prefix. How do I escape the prefix?

Comment: CakePHP adds prefix automatically by context.
So you must add
'prefix' => false
to skip or reset the prefix context

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP adds prefix automatically by context.
So you must add

```
'prefix' => false
```

to skip or reset the prefix context

new route:

```
['prefix' => false, 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $recipe->user->id]
```